# SQL to Count status text and change some of those status texts (and their count) based on a date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Spent a while looking for this but did not quite find a solution. The problem: get counts for the status value in one column. Pretty simple so far, how ever I also want to change/ignore some of them when the DueDate (and it can be null) is past due based on current date and NOT complete. Also include empty strings for the status. Example Data (forgive the date show as text...assume it is a SQL date type - just wanted to make this more readable):

```
Current Date Apr : April 4, 2016
```

Data In DB Table `DispatchStatus`

```
Status        Due Date
=======================================
Complete      Mar 1, 2015                  <-- would not be Late since Complete
Complete      null
Complete      July 12, 2016
Complete      July 16, 2016
Started       Mar 3, 2017
Started       null
Started       Feb 9, 2015                   <-- Late
OnDevice      June, 2016
OnDevice      Dec 3, 2015                   <-- Late
Dispatched    Nov 16, 2015                  <-- Late
Dispatched    null
Dispatched    Nov 20, 2016
              Nov 15, 2017
              null
              Jan 15, 2016                  <-- Late
```

The query should return:

```
Status        Count
=========================
Complete        4
Started         2
OnDevice        1
                2
Dispatched      2
Late            4
```

Thanks!

Comment: How is `Dispatched    Nov 16, 2015 ` late? I only see one late here.

Comment: Yep. Fixed that now. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression together with `COUNT`:

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATE = '20160404'

SELECT
    Status =
        CASE 
            WHEN DueDate <= @currentDate AND ISNULL(Status, '') <> 'Complete' THEN 'Late'
            ELSE Status
        END,
    COUNT(*)
FROM DispatchStatus
GROUP BY
    CASE 
        WHEN DueDate <= @currentDate AND ISNULL(Status, '') <> 'Complete' THEN 'Late'
        ELSE Status
    END
```

*I think your sample current date should be `Apr 4, 2016` based on your sample output.*

Comment: Thanks! You are correct - was trying to put today's date in there. Once other question - the real world scenario also includes a fairly large where clause (to filter down the list). Would that just be tacked to the When clause? Keep you posted on how this works out. Thanks again

Comment: I think so. Try it out and let me know how it went.

Comment: Looking really good! Slipped the Where between the FROM and the GROUP BY. Have to expand the data, but I think I'm there. Thanks again for the help - saved me hours.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.